# C# Type Erasure Issues

Tags: c#, generics

Putting together a state machine in C#. I have an interface and abstract implementing class as:

```
public interface IState<SD> where SD : IStateData {
    T EnterState<T>(InputData inputData, SD movementData) where T : IState<SD>;
}

public abstract class AMovementState : IState<MovementData> {
    public abstract AMovementState EnterState<AMovementState>(InputData inputData, MovementData movementData);
}
```

`MovementData` implements `IStateData` so this seems like it should work fine. However I'm getting the compile error:

> Error CS0425: The constraints for type parameter `AMovementState' of method`AMovementState.EnterState(InputData, MovementData)' must match the constraints for type parameter `T' of interface method`IState.EnterState(InputData, MovementData)'. Consider using an explicit interface implementation instead (CS0425) (Assembly-CSharp)

I think that this is an issue with type erasure but I'm not 100%. Do I need to rework my approach or am I missing something stupid? Coming from mostly a Java background.

Comment: C# (actually .NET generics in general) does not use type erasure.

Comment: Java uses type erasure.  C# does not.

Comment: Conceptually this doesn't make sense to me. `AMovementState` is in implementing class of `IState<SD>`. Why does returning `AMovementState` not satisfy the interface method signature. Isn't this the cruz of polymorphism?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I think that this is an issue with type erasure

C# does not have type erasure. C# has actual generic types deeply baked into the runtime.

To start with, you have made a common error; you did this:

```
class C {
  C M<C>() { ... }
```

Oh the pain.  This is **so hard to read**. The C in the method is the C declared by the method, not the C declared by the class. You did the same thing:

```
public abstract class AMovementState : IState<MovementData> {
  public abstract AMovementState EnterState<AMovementState>(
    InputData inputData, MovementData movementData);
}
```

Same thing here. You have declared **two** things, both called `AMovementState`, one a class type and one a type parameter. Please don't do that. It is incredibly misleading for the reader of the code.

Second, once you solve that problem:  C# requires that a generic method which implements an interface method match exactly the constraints of that interface method.

Now, you may note that in this particular case, there is no *logical* requirement that the implementing method have the constraint. The type system could have been designed so that in this case, calling via the class gives a smaller constraint and calling via the interface gives a larger constraint, and that would be type safe.

But C# was not designed that way; it was designed so that constraints are required to match, even in cases where that is not strictly speaking necessary.

So, you have two choices:

- Add the constraint to the abstract method, or
- Do what the error message says. Create an explicit interface method that calls the class method.

That is either:

```
public abstract class AMovementState : IState<MovementData> {
    public abstract M EnterState<M>
    (InputData inputData, MovementData movementData)
    where M : IState<MovementData>;
}
```

or

```
public abstract class AMovementState : IState<MovementData> {
    public abstract M EnterState<M>
    (InputData inputData, MovementData movementData);

    M IState<MovementData>.EnterState<M> 
    (InputData inputData, MovementData movementData)
    {
      this.EnterState<M>(inputData, movementData);
    }
}
```

Ironically, C# does not allow the constraints to be repeated on the explicit interface method; it infers them automatically. I've always thought of that as one of the oddest features of C#.

More generally: you may be suffering from *Genericity Happiness Disease*, that is the desire to make things generic even though it is unnecessary and hard to understand. Ask yourself whether a thing actually needs to be generic. Generics can be very difficult to reason about; maybe there is a simpler abstraction you can use.

Answer (score 1):

Your class does not implement the interface, instead only one specific case.

You need to replicate the method generically:

```
public abstract class AMovementState : IState<MovementData> {
    public abstract T EnterState<T>(InputData inputData, MovementData movementData) where T : IState<MovementData>;
}
```

The reason is simple: if some code holds a reference to a `IState<MovementData>`, they will call the method `EnterState` generically, therefore the implementation must also be generic.